# Will below command work as it as on jenkins for running my jar file with command line arguments?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, jar, executable-jar

I have built an executable jar file which is also a standalone SpringBoot Application. The requirement is that I have to run this jar file from command line which also provides command line arguments which are meant to override application.properties properties and will be used further.
I have tried and this works perfectly when ran from Windows Command Prompt.

Now I further want to deploy this on jenkins and run the same jar file usign jenkins using the command:Note that the command is important since it overrides application.properties.

Will it work in jenkins? Should i go with "Execute Shell" or "Execute Windows batch command" for it in jenkins? I would be trying it but need o know .

Command: java -jar myJArName.jar --server.port=10 --another.argument=1 --another.argument=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `execute shell` as you mentioned above **if**:

- Java is installed on the host that Jenkins runs on
- `java` is part of `$PATH` (you can check this by running `which java` on your jenkins host)
- `myJarName.jar` is actually on the host jenkins runs on

Btw. I assume Jenkins runs on a Linux host. Otherwise you might have to use `Execute Windows batch command` which will work in a similar way to `execute shell`, but I never used it.